# How can I position a jQuery dialog over a (Google) map?

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps, jquery-ui-dialog

If my map has too many points on it I want my users to zoom in to view fewer points.  I'd also like to display other notifications, not sure if I should do this on the map or not, but it would relate directly to the stuff on the map.

Anyone know of an easy way to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/) plugin.  It's very customizable with regard to how it works.

Comment: Exactly what I am using.  The problem is the position.  I don't want it over the entire page, just on the map in the corner or something.  It needs to be very low profile as it isn't the most important part of the page, just part of the map itself.

Comment: Make it non-modal and adjust the height/width and position to be where you want it.  Set the z-index so that it floats above your map.

Answer (score 0):

Find the X and the Y of the Div that holds the map and just place a lightbox or something there.

Comment: Easy to do with jQuery?  I haven't seen anything that does that, but I will look.